# Problem about install the torch bindings for tiny-cuda-nn: "error: subprocess-exited-with-error"

Tags: python, c++, deep-learning, conda

I am trying to intsall the NeRFstudio, in the step install the torch bindings for tiny-cuda-nn(

```
pip install ninja git+https://github.com/NVlabs/tiny-cuda-nn/#subdirectory=bindings/torch)
```

I meet a problem.

The problem is :

**- error: subprocess-exited-with-error**

**  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1**
╰─> [10 lines of output]
C:\Users\kirkd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-poguu56o\bindings/torch\setup.py:5: DeprecationWarning: pkg_resources is deprecated as an API. See https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/pkg_resources.html
from pkg_resources import parse_version
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "C:\Users\kirkd\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-poguu56o\bindings/torch\setup.py", line 72, in 
raise RuntimeError("Could not locate a supported Microsoft Visual C++ installation")
RuntimeError: Could not locate a supported Microsoft Visual C++ installation
Building PyTorch extension for tiny-cuda-nn version 1.7
Obtained compute capability 86 from PyTorch
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
**error: metadata-generation-failed
**
× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

I tried to upgrade the pip but it still not solve my problem.

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

**Requirement already satisfied**

Answer (score 0):

Install Visual studio code with c++ library